# Lua: String is nil after explicitly checking for nil

Tags: lua, null

I have made a script to get patient data from a database.

It works for the first few hundreds of patients, but at some random point i get the error:

*** lua run error BatchDicomMove.lua:91: attempt to compare nil with string in 'dofile('BatchDicomMove.lua')'

Even despite I explicitly checking whether the argument is nil or not.
Furthermore when I make changes in the code (like adding an empty line). The error just occur in another place where a. is accessed.

What could be wrong?

```
-- execute this script by calling: dgate "--lua:dofile('BatchDicomMove.lua')"

-- MOP: Query=STUDY|SERIES Move=STUDY+StudyInstanceUID
-- GEPACS_RSD: Query=* Move=SERIES

inputFile       = 'PatientList.txt'
srcAet          = 'NUKALFA'
destAet         = 'ONCO_PACS_RD'
modalities      = {'CT','PT'}
includeStr      = {'Standard','standard','AC'}  -- if non are desired enter {}
includeOrAnd    = 'or'                          -- choose 'and', 'or'
excludeStr      = {'NAC','CTAC'}                -- if non are desired enter {}
excludeOrAnd    = 'nor'                         -- choose 'neither', 'nor'
select          = 'newest'                      -- choose 'newest', 'oldest', 'all'
relativeToTime  = 'before'                      -- choose 'before', 'after', 'exact'




for line in io.lines(inputFile) do
    -- Loop through all patients

    date = ''
    date1 = ''
    date2 = ''
    stringSplit = string.find(line,' ')
    if stringSplit == nil then
        ptId = line
    else
        ptId = string.sub(line,0,stringSplit-1)
        date = string.sub(line,stringSplit+1)
        if string.len(date) == 18 then
            stringSplit = string.find(date,' ')
            if stringSplit == nil then
                date = ''
            else
                date = ''
                date1 = string.sub(date,0,stringSplit-1)
                date2 = string.sub(line,stringSplit+1)
            end
        elseif string.len(date) ~= 9 then
            date = ''
        end
    end
    -- ptIdAlts ensures that the patient will be found nomater if '-' is included in the ID or not
    stringSplit = string.find(ptId,'-')
    if stringSplit == nil then
        ptId = string.sub(ptId,0,7) .. '-' .. string.sub(ptId,8)
    end
    stringSplit = string.find(ptId,'-')
    ptIdAlts = {ptId,string.sub(ptId,0,stringSplit-1) .. string.sub(ptId,stringSplit+1)}

    print('  Query: patient', ptIdAlts[1], 'from', srcAet, 'to', destAet)

    -- an extra loop have been added as part of implementation of ptIdAlts
    b = {}
    for key, ptId in ipairs(ptIdAlts) do
        for key, modality in ipairs(modalities) do

            -- create query for dicom move
            q = newdicomobject()
            q.PatientID = ptId
            q.Modality = modality
            -- values to retrive should be included in the query
            q.StudyInstanceUID  = ''
            q.SeriesInstanceUID = ''
            q.PatientName = ''
            q.SeriesDescription = ''
            q.StudyDate = ''

            -- execute query for infomation on patient data on the source machine
            a = dicomquery(srcAet, 'SERIES', q) -- sets QueryRetrieveLevel at call time
            for i=1,#a do 
                b[#b+1] = a[i-1] 
            end
        end
    end

    -- Remove unwanted resultes

    c = {}
    if date ~= '' then
        for i, a in ipairs(b) do
            if a.StudyDate ~= nil then
                if relativeToTime == 'exact' then
                    if a.StudyDate == date then
                        c[#c+1] = a
                    end
                elseif relativeToTime == 'before' then
                    if a.StudyDate <= date then
                        c[#c+1] = a
                    end
                else
                    if a.StudyDate >= date then
                        c[#c+1] = a
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    elseif (date1 ~= '') and (date2 ~= '') then
        for i, a in ipairs(b) do
            if (a.StudyDate ~= nil) and (a.StudyDate >= date1) and (a.StudyDate <= date2) then
                c[#c+1] = a
            end
        end
    else
        c = b
    end
    b = c

    c = {}
    if #includeStr ~= 0 then
        for key, a in ipairs(b) do
            if a.SeriesDescription ~= nil then
                if includeOrAnd == 'or' then
                    for key, include in ipairs(includeStr) do
                        if string.match(a.SeriesDescription,include) ~= nil then
                            c[#c+1] = a
                            break
                        end
                    end
                else
                    for key, include in ipairs(includeStr) do
                        if string.match(a.SeriesDescription,include) == nil then
                            break
                        end
                        c[#c+1] = a
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        b = c
    end

    c = {}
    if #excludeStr ~= 0 then
        for key, a in ipairs(b) do
            if a.SeriesDescription ~= nil then
                if excludeOrAnd == 'nor' then
                    for key, exclude in ipairs(excludeStr) do
                        if string.match(a.SeriesDescription,exclude) ~= nil then
                            break
                        end
                        c[#c+1] = a
                    end
                else
                    for key, exclude in ipairs(excludeStr) do
                        if string.match(a.SeriesDescription,exclude) == nil then
                            c[#c+1] = a
                            break
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        b = c
    end

    c = {}
    if select == 'newest' then
        for key, modality in ipairs(modalities) do
            for i, a in ipairs(b) do
                if a.StudyDate ~= nil then
                    if c[key] == nil then
                        c[key] = a
                    elseif c[key].StudyDate < a.StudyDate then
                        c[key] = a
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    elseif select == 'oldest' then
        for key, modality in ipairs(modalities) do
            for i, a in ipairs(b) do
                if a.StudyDate ~= nil then
                    if c[key] == nil then
                        c[key] = a
                    elseif c[key].StudyDate > a.StudyDate then
                        c[key] = a
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    else
        c = b
    end
    b = c

    n = #b
    print('  Query results:', n)

    for key, a in ipairs(b) do
        cmd = newdicomobject()
        cmd.PatientID = b.PatientID
        cmd.StudyInstanceUID = b.StudyInstanceUID
        cmd.SeriesInstanceUID = b.SeriesInstanceUID

        if srcAet == 'MOP_SCP' then
            cmd.QueryRetrieveLevel = 'STUDY' -- only level supported by the MOP for dicom move
            cmd.Modality = b.Modality
        else
            cmd.QueryRetrieveLevel = 'SERIES' -- tested on GEPACS_RSD
        end

        -- execute the move
        --dicommove(srcAet, destAet, cmd);
    end
end
print('  Done.')
```

Comment: Which is line 91 in that snippet exactly? What line of input is it failing on? That error comes from [relational operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.2) other than `==` and `~=` so check that you have those guarded.

Answer (score 4):

There are comparisons in this file on line 90 and 94:

```
line 90: if a.StudyDate <= date then
line 94: if a.StudyDate >= date then
```

We can see that a.StudyDate is *not* nil because you checked for it at line 84.
Therefore, my guess is that *date* could be nil.

Another place is on line 102:

```
if (a.StudyDate ~= nil) and (a.StudyDate >= date1) and (a.StudyDate <= date2)
```

Again, check that *date1* and *date2* are not nil.

In the same vein, you should probably check 'c[key].StudyDate' line 178.

Comment: I posted an answer too, but cocked up the line numbering so thought it best to delete.  However, the important point I noticed is that the code checks only for `date ~= ''` rather than `date ~= nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but date, date1, and date2 are never reported to be nil. It is always the a.<somthing> part that becomes nil.  I can print the value onto the screen right before an error occurs an the value is not nil.